# No /usr/local/cuda/ directory after Cuda installation

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, cuda

I have installed Cuda with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-10
```

and then checked the version with:

```
    $ nvcc --version
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Sun_Feb_14_21:12:58_PST_2021
    Cuda compliation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
    Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0
```

However, there is no `/usr/local/cuda/` directory and so I do not know what to do as I think having this directory is necessary to install cuDNN (which is the end goal).

I am using lubuntu 21.04 and an NVIDIA GeForce GT 720M GPU with a legacy 390 driver.

So if you could tell me what to do in order to install Cuda correctly so that there is a `/usr/local/cuda/` directory and I can install cuDNN, that would be great!

Edit: After installing cudnn by copying the files from the tar file into /usr/lib/cuda/ (thanks to Tilman) I tried to verify the installation by trying to compile the mnistCUDNN file in the /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v8 directory (as suggested in the Nvidia docs)  but that directory also doesn't exist. Any idea on where it would be?

Thank you.

Comment: `apt` packages do not usually install their stuff under `/usr/local`. You can see where the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package did install its stuff with the command `dpkg -L nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. What makes you think you need a `/usr/local/cuda` directory?

Comment: @Tilman thanks it seems to be installed in /usr/lib/cuda/. The Nvidia tutorial https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#installlinux suggests that /usr/local/cuda/ is the cuda toolkit directory but I assume that I can just replace that with /usr/lib/cuda/?

Comment: You're tangled up in some old Nvidia instructions (CUDA 8), where the assumed installation is all under one directory, with a bin, lib64, and include.  Later CUDA releases (and the Ubuntu installs) have a new way, they sprinkle the CUDA bins, libs, and included into the existing system areas (so no modifications needed to PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH).  Put your dnn files into those system areas (along with the cuda files already there).